# External hard drive does not shut down

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, motherboard

When I shut down Ubuntu, my external USB hard drive does not shut down (at all), while still powering off other USB devices (such as my headphones and keyboard).

I have a B365M DS3H WIFI motherboard if that makes a difference.

Hard drive shuts down normally with Windows.

How do I make it shut down normally?

Edit: even after turning the hard drive off and powering off normally, it still is getting power when it shouldn’t after shutdown.

Comment: Is this external drive powered only by the USB port? Or is there a separate power adapter for the hard drive as well?

Comment: @Matigo only the usb port directly to the motherboard, no other power.

Comment: I don't know why, but I have one of those USB drives with a light on it.  And after shutting down my Ubuntu 20.10 system, the light on this USB drive remains on.  I haven't tried this with Windows, but I always thought it was an issue with my hardware (i.e., that the motherboard is still providing power).  Since it's off, what OS it was running before it turned off shouldn't matter?  Anyway, I'm glad I'm not the only one seeing this, but I'm not bothered enough to do anything about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a "feature" of [your Gigabyte motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B365M-DS3H-rev-10/sp#sp) called ["ON/OFF Charge"](https://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm). From the feature's description:

> GIGABYTE's latest motherboards are equipped with ON/OFF Charge technology which allows you not only to charge your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch, but it allows you to Quick Charge it. As an added bonus, it can even be charged when your PC is turned off, so even if you forget to plug it into your charger after you've synced up your music, it will be fully charged when you need it.
>
> [...]
>
> * Maximum 3 devices can be charged at the same time. Charging current may vary with PSU 5V stand-by spec.

As it's unlikely that the motherboard is looking *specifically* for Apple devices based on a USB device manufacturer ID, I would venture that the motherboard simply provides 5V of uninterrupted power to a maximum of three USB ports regardless of whether the machine is on or not. If this is the case, then the external drive would not know to shut itself off unless specifically given a command to do so.

Because you've said that the drive will properly wind down when Windows shuts down, this has me thinking that the drive is waiting for a command from the host OS that Ubuntu may not be sending for whatever reason (some drives wait for `power-off` and others wait for `eject`).

One possible solution would be to write a script that is run whenever the system enters into a shutdown cycle to first unmount USB partitions, then send the a "power-off" command for a given device.

If you'd like to give it a try, here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Get the `UUID` for the USB disk with `blkid`:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   This will give you a list of all your devices, and you'll be looking for the one that represents the USB disk(s) you want to shut down. You may see something similar to this:

   ```
   /dev/sdc1: UUID="AzJSHp-stpU-1ArB-YOMD-G7OD-l1Uz-xJhQIh" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="04592289-01"
   ```
2. Create a shell script in your home directory (or anywhere, really):

   ```
   vi ~/sleep-disks.sh
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use any text editor.* `vi` *is not a requirement.*
3. Paste the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   sudo hdparm -Y /dev/disk/by-uuid/<disk-uuid>
   exit 0
   ```

   If you have some trouble using `hdparm` you can use this approach:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   disk_uuid="<disk-uuid>"

   udisksctl unmount -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/${disk_uuid}
   udisksctl power-off -b /dev/disk/by-uuid/${disk_uuid}

   exit 0
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `<disk-uuid>` *with the proper value determined in step 1.*
4. Save the file
5. Ensure the script is executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x ~/sleep-disks.sh
   ```
6. Create a new systemd service record:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/sleep-disks.service
   ```
7. Paste the following:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Shut down external disks
   DefaultDependencies=no
   Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
   # This works because it is installed in the target and will be
   #   executed before the target state is entered
   # Also consider kexec.target

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   User=<YOUR_USER>
   Group=<YOUR_USER>
   ExecStart=/home/<YOUR_USER>/sleep-disks.sh

   [Install]
   WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `<YOUR_USER>` *with your actual username, and* `ExecStart=` *should point to the actual location of the shell script.*
8. Save the file
9. Reload the daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```

This will ensure the `sleep-disks.sh` script is run every time the computer is told to shut down, reboot, or halt (suspend).

The `hdparm -Y` command tells the external disk to drop to its lowest power state, which is "off". From [the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/hdparm.8.html):

```
-Y     Force  an  IDE  drive to immediately enter the lowest power consumption
       sleep mode, causing it to shut down completely.  A hard or soft reset is
       required  before  the drive can be accessed again (the Linux IDE driver
       will automatically handle issuing a reset if/when needed).  The current
       power mode status can be checked using the -C option.
```

The `udisksctl unmount` will garante the disk will be unmounted, so `udisksctl power-off` will power off the disk.

Alternatively ... perhaps you can just disable the "ON/OFF Charge" feature in your BIOS if this is something you never use